# How to add subtitles to any YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, subtitles

I would like to know if there is a way to add subtitles to any YouTube video.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is the auto-generated English subtitles for youtube in the cc part when you click Settings in the video. And Some YouTube channels allow you to contribute by adding subtitles to there video, and you can for sure do this if it is your channel. Also if none of this works there are some phones and computers that have an automatic subtitle for any voice that comes on the screen, like on android devices when you press the volume button the live caption pop up. Hope this helped

Answer (score -1):

You can add subtitles as long as the owner of the video allows it, if they have activated the community contribution then you are good to go!

[Here](https://translate.video/how-to-translate-youtube-videos/) I found the steps to do so:

Step by step guide

**Translate YouTube Subtitles**

1. Go to the YouTube video that you want to translate
2. Click on the settings icon
3. Click on Subtitles/CC
4. Find your language.
5. If you don’t see it, don’t worry. You can get YouTube to do this automatically.
   Click on Auto-translate and choose your language. If auto translate isn’t clickable, first check an existing subtitles language and then try again. This should work
6. YouTube uses Google Translate to create the subtitles translation so it’s not always perfect.
   However, this is better than nothing and you still get a better understanding of what’s being said. And there you have it, subtitles automatically translated into your language

**Add Subtitles Translation Contribution**

7. If you’d like to help others that speak your native language understand the video, you can contribute your own translation or edit the auto-translation
8. Go to the YouTube video
9. Click on the three dots and select Add translations. Sometimes the video you requested isn’t enabled for community contribution. If it is enabled you can proceed.
10. You can choose to translate the Title & description or the Subtitles/CC. In this case we’ll translate the Subtitles
11. Select the language that you want to translate the video into
12. Choose your language and click on Set language
13. If your language has already been translated automatically or by someone else, you can edit the translations yourself
14. If not, you’ll be able to see the original language separated by the timecodes.
    Input the translation for each sentence or autotranslate and go through to check and alter it. Then, click on Submit contribution. If you’re finished click on Yes, ready to be reviewed.
15. And there you have it. The subtitles translated into your language!

There's a video also, check the site cause I copied the steps but the photos won't show, and that's the best way to follow the instructions.